# Why is the object inside div tag covered on footer tag?

Tags: html, css

My images of `div` tag covered `footer` tag. Here is several ways I tried but didn't work:

- check the css of `justify-content:space-between`
- check the css`position` whether effect this problem
- check the css`z-index` whether effect this problem
- switch the tags containing images inline into blocks


  And none of those did work....

```css
#productteam>section>:nth-child(2)>section>.col3{width:100%;position:relative;}
#productteam>section>:nth-child(2)>section>.col3>:first-child{position:absolute;overflow:hidden;}
#productteam>section>:nth-child(2)>section>.col3>:first-child::before{content:"";width:100%;height:100%;
top:0;left:0;z-index:1;position:absolute;opacity:0;transition:all 0.5s 0.2s;
 background-image:linear-gradient(to top, rgba(50,50,50,0.7) 20%, rgba(50,50,50,0.6) 30%,
  rgba(50,50,50,0) 100%);}
#productteam>section>:nth-child(2)>section>.col3:hover>:first-child::before{opacity: 0.8;}
#productteam>section>:nth-child(2)>section>.col3>a{border-radius: 1rem;}
#productteam>section>:nth-child(2)>section>.col3>a>img{transition:all 0.2s;transform:scale(1);}
#productteam>section>:nth-child(2)>section>.col3:hover>a>img{transform:scale(1.2);}
#productteam>section>:nth-child(2)>section>.col3 p{top:14rem;left: 2rem; z-index: 2;position: absolute;
visibility: hidden;opacity: 0;transition: all 0.5s 0.2s;font-size: 1.25rem;font-style: italic;
font-weight: bold; color: white;line-height: 2rem;}
#productteam>section>:nth-child(2)>section>.col3:hover p{visibility: visible;opacity: 1;top:9rem;}
```

```html
<div id="productteam">
  <section class="container paddingV2">
   <div class="flexbox dividingLine flexDirectionC alignItemsCenter marginAll1">
    <h1>Prodution Team</h1>
    <h2>製作團隊</h2>    
   </div>
   <div class="marginAll1">
    <section class="flexbox justifyContentBetween">
     <div class="col3 marginAll1">
      <a href="#"><img src="images/productteam1.jpg" alt="藤林秀麿"></a>
      <p>總監<br>
      藤林秀麿</p>
     </div>
     <div class="col3 flexbox flexDirectionC marginAll1">
      <a href="#"><img src="images/productteam2.jpg" alt="青沼英二"></a>
      <p>製作人<br>
      青沼英二</p>
     </div>
     <div class="col3 flexbox flexDirectionC marginAll1">
      <a href="#"><img src="images/productteam3.jpg" alt="戶田昭吾"></a>
      <p>編劇<br>
      戶田昭吾</p>
     </div>
     <div class="col3 flexbox flexDirectionC marginAll1">
      <a href="#"><img src="images/productteam4.jpg" alt="堂田卓宏"></a>
      <p>程式<br>
      堂田卓宏</p>
     </div>
     <div class="col3 flexbox flexDirectionC marginAll1">
      <a href="#"><img src="images/productteam5.jpg" alt="瀧澤智"></a>
      <p>美術<br>
      瀧澤智</p>
     </div>
     <div class="col3 flexbox flexDirectionC marginAll1">
      <a href="#"><img src="images/productteam6.jpg" alt="若井淑"></a>
      <p>音樂<br>
      若井淑</p>
     </div>
    </section> 
   </div>
  </section>
 </div>
 <!-- 店鋪搜尋 著作商標 -->
 <footer class="bgDarkgray">
  <nav class="container">
   <div>
    <a href="#">footer</a>
   <div>
   </div>
  </nav>
 </footer>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be helpful to see the desired design, but just to fix the elements overlap you can remove `position: absolute` from a tag and add color to p tag with text, attached codepen with the final result: https://codepen.io/Liveindream/pen/zYxReOY